# Indenting ListView items

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to indent the items of a listview so they display the elements of a listView in a semicircular pattern. For achieving this result I have written the following code. The code works fine when the scrolling stops, *however during scrolling, the listview doesn't indentation doesn't depict semi circle and sometimes shows slanted indentation instead of semi circle.* I have been trying to solve this problem but feeling kind of stuck. A little insight/help on this problem would be great.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i< visibleItemCount/2; i++) {
        shiftRight[i] = 300 * (( i* 1.0f) / imageIntArray.length); 
        view.getChildAt(i).setPadding((int) shiftRight[i], 0, 0, 0);    
    }

    shiftRight[i] = 300 * (( i* 1.0f) / imageIntArray.length);
    for(int j=visibleItemCount/2; j<visibleItemCount; j++) {                   
        view.getChildAt(j).setPadding((int) shiftRight[i], 0, 0, 0);
        i--;
    }

    view.invalidate();
}
```

Regards

Comment: +1 for a great question. I improved it a bit for clarity.